# Вставить изображение из буфера обмена в input с помощью jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть ли какой-то способ с помощью jquery вставить изображение из буфера обмена в input?

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: jQuery — набор функций JavaScript, фокусирующийся на взаимодействии JavaScript и HTML. Библиотека jQuery помогает легко получать доступ к любому элементу DOM, обращаться к атрибутам и содержимому элементов DOM, манипулировать ими. Также библиотека jQuery предоставляет удобный API для работы с AJAX.

Comment: в 2022 году уже мало того, что все отказываются давно от него, но вот зачем пытаться все операции на нём совершать - мне вообще не ясно.....какие-то буферы, шмуферы... может ещё многопоточность включать?)) вот серьёзно